# Double breakpoint syntax in chrome debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I was debugging some code in Chrome and randomly some of the breakpoints I had started showing up like this

[image]

The syntax (IMO) would imply that it is breaking on both of those points, but it doesn't.  In fact, it doesn't perform any different than a regular breakpoint.  But I am left thinking, What is this?  Why is it here?  How did it appear?

FYI: My Google Chrome is up to date (Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit))

EDIT: the second one is clickable and is another breakpoint when clicked but the question still remains.  What are they?  And why did they just suddenly appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is a regular line break. The second one is a break on the call to `clearErrorMessage`. In this case they're really the same, but if you had chained function calls or nested functions here the multi-line breakpoint becomes incredibly useful.

Comment: Any idea why I am just seeing them now?  I have been working in this application for a year now and am using Chrome breakpoints daily

Comment: Chrome frequently updates and adds new features all the time. I can't find exactly when this kind of breakpoint support was added, but you could [peruse through the release notes to find out more](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/).